# SearchKit nested field with key, value

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkit

For a new problem, I would add a RefinmentFilter for nested fields and inside key, value pairs.

Our query should looks like this:

```
POST search_de/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "attributes": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "techData"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "key": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "techData.key": "COLOUR"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "values": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "techData.valueKeyword"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This our sample data:

```
"techData": [
      {
        "name": "Leiterquerschnitt in mm²",
        "valueKeyword": "0,14",
        "key": "PL_DYN_QUERSCHNITT"
      },
      {
        "name": "Außendurchmesser in mm",
        "valueKeyword": "1,1",
        "key": "PL_DURCHMESSERAUSSEN"
      },
      {
        "name": "Aderfarbe",
        "valueKeyword": "grün/gelb",
        "key": "PL_COLOUR"
      }
    ],
```

Is there a way to achive this with standard filters?
If not, what is the easiest way to adapt SearchKit to our needed behavor?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: No, sorry. We changed our data.